# Reversing a linked list in python: What is wrong in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to reverse a linked list in python. Below is my code which doesn't work (gives an error of 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next' at the while statement):

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self,  head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        currentNode = head
        previousNode=None
        while currentNode.next is not None:
            temp=currentNode.next
            currentNode.next=previousNode
            previousNode=currentNode
            currentNode=temp
        
        currentNode.next=previousNode
        return currentNode
```

In my mind, what I am trying to do is that when it reaches the last node in the list (the one with next being None), it exits the while loop, and then out of the loop points, point that last node to the previous and return it as the head of the reversed list.

What is wrong in the above code and how can I fix it?

Comment: What are you sending as `haed` to the function? are you sure it's `ListNode` and not `None`? add the linked list initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

`def reverseList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:`

we can see that `head` is either an instance of `ListNode` or `None`. After the next line:

```
currentNode = head
```

we know that `currentNode` too is either a `ListNode` or `None`.

Then, when you check the condition:

```
while currentNode.next is not None:
```

... `currentNode` can be `None`, and `None.next` doesn't exist and gives an error.

Luckily, if you look at the code, `currentNode` will not be a `None` at any time after the first loop. (Why? Because it gets the old value of `currentNode.next`, which we know isn't `None` because in that case the loop would have ended.)

So the only thing you need to care about is `head` being `None`, since that is the only time you can get the error.

`head is None` means the list is empty, and the reverse of an empty list is still empty, so you can insert:

```
if head is None:
    return None
```

at the top of your `reverseList` method, and that should work just fine.

Comment: That seems to work perfectly. Thanks a lot. What I still don’t understand though is: if the head of a given instance is not None (i.e., is not empty), shouldn’t my original code have worked?

Comment: Yes, it should. What is it you don't understand?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Turned out that Leetcode apparently would give such error if one of the test cases has a head of None (thought it would work for the other test instances, but apparently if at least one of them have that issue, it will give such error). Thanks a lot for your help!